# Yii2 max_size validation issue

Tags: validation, yii2

This is my action:

```
public function actionCustom() {
    $model = new Custom();

    $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());

    if ($model->validate()) {
        // emptying the model's data
        $model = new Custom();

        var_dump('good');
    } else {
        var_dump('bad');
    }

    var_dump($_FILES);

    return $this->render('custom', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

And this is my model:

```
class Custom extends Model
{
    public $file;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
//            ['file', 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'txt'], 'maxSize' => 1024 * 100]
            ['file', 'file', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 100],
        ];
    }
}
```

When I try to upload a file which size exceeds the maxSize rule I set, the client-side validation displays an error and I can't submit the form by clicking on the button and this is all fine, but I can force submitting by typing something like this in the console like how a hacker would do:

`document.forms[0].submit()`

And I get this output:

```
C:\wamp64\www3\controllers\SiteController.php:138:string 'good' (length=4)

C:\wamp64\www3\controllers\SiteController.php:143:
array (size=1)
  'Custom' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'file' => string 'tste.txt' (length=8)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          'file' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\phpDE60.tmp' (length=25)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          'file' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          'file' => int 818064
```

`string 'good'` means that the file has passed the validation, but how?! The size of the file I sent was 818064 and it is bigger than 102400 (1024 * 100) file size limit which I set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance()` method mentioned in the official docs example?

```
$model = new UploadForm();

if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
    if ($model->upload()) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        return;
    }
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#wiring-up

Comment: No, I haven't. Do you mean I should try to set `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file')` to "file" attribute before validating?

Comment: @Razip Yes, git a try.

Comment: @Razip your validation rule is just being ignored if you dont set the file property manualy (you can enforce this with `skipOnEmpty = false`)

Comment: @csminb, would you please tell how it can enforced?

Comment: ['file', 'file', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 100, 'skipOnEmpty' => false ],